# Software Updater extremely slow (Ubuntu 16.04.1-64)

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, update-manager

I have two computers, both running Ubuntu 14.04 fine. I then upgraded to 16.04 and observed that Software Updater became awfully slow to download new packages from http://archive.ubuntu.com/. Has someone had the same problem? As I said above, SU was working fine on 14.04.

I tried other repositories to no avail.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Fausto

Comment: When you say that you "tried other repositories to no avail" does that mean that they were unreachable or that they were also slow? Also, have you checked that this isn't a broader problem that encompasses network problems across the system?

Comment: I meant that they were equally slow. That never happened with 14.04 or previous Ubuntu versions. Not sure if that helps, but when I ping the repository located in my own city, which used to be quite fast, ping says it still is (fast).
>>>
64 bytes from ubuntu.c3sl.ufpr.br (200.236.31.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=5.52 ms
>>>
Nothing has changed in my home network. Nothing. All I did was to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04.